# How do i compare each element in an array with each element in List?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, list, hashmap

I have list of elements with 20 items and an array with 5 items, I need to compare each item for common properties and if it matches..I need to filter them in to a list for o/p. How do I compare them effectively, without doing 20 * 5 = 100 comparisons. May be by using hashmap? Please help...Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ-to-objects extension method [Enumerable.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx) is probably the most concise way of expressing this:

```
List<MyListType> matches = myList
    .Join(myArray, 
          myListItem => myListItem.someProperty, //if this prop
          myArrayItem => myArrayItem.someProperty, //and this prop match
          (myListItem, myArrayItem) => myListItem) //project to...
    .ToList();
```

Internally, this uses a hash-table like structure created from the left hand side of the join (`myList` above), then iterates the right hand side of the join (`myArray` above) looking for matches in the set created from the left hand side.

This significantly speeds up processing when compared to the (naive) Cartesian product that you describe above (*"20 * 5 = 100 comparisons"*)

Effectively, it does something like this:

```
var lookup = lhs.ToLookup(leftItem => leftItem.someProp);
var matches = rhs.SelectMany(rightItem => 
    lookup[rightItem.someProp]
        .Select(leftItem => MethodToBeCalledWithTwoMatchingItems(leftItem, rightItem)));
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more efficient to hash just the smaller list, or the one that changes less:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var result = list1.Where(item => hashSet.Contains(item.Property));
```